# How to run callback after mongoose findOneAndUpdate finish updating?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my API i have the express's `app.put` method,where i search in a collection for a document with a specific title with mongoose's `findOneAndUpdate` method and update it.

```
    app.put("/articles/:articleTitle",(req, res) => {

        Article.findOneAndUpdate({
               title: req.params.articleTitle
           }, {
               title: req.body.title,
               content: req.body.content
           }, (err, foundArticle) => {
               err ? res.send("Error !") : foundArticle ? res.send("Article found.Updating...") : res.send("NO articles found to update!")
           })

       })
```

How can i run a callback function AFTER the update has finished,and maybe return the updated document ?
I have tried to add a `.then` at the end of `findOneAndUpdate` method but it throws me this error : *"MongooseError: Query was already executed: Article.findOneAndUpdate..."*

I have also tried to pass the method's return value in a variable and access it in `.then` but it throws the same error like so :

```
    app.put("/articles/:articleTitle",(req, res) => {
        
       const doc = Article.findOneAndUpdate({
               title: req.params.articleTitle
           }, {
               title: req.body.title,
               content: req.body.content
           },{returnDocument: 'after'}, (err, foundArticle) => {
               err ? res.send("Error !") : foundArticle ? res.send("Article found.Updating...") : res.send("NO articles found to update!")
           }).then( () =>{ console.log(doc) })
           
       })
```

**EDIT : It seems that when i simply add the option `returnDocument: 'after'` as a parameter,it gives me access to the "after" document inside its own method callback,hmm,i have to check the docs but if anyone knows the common practice to do this i would appreciate it !**

```
        Article.findOneAndUpdate({
            title: req.params.articleTitle
        }, {
            title: req.body.title,
            content: req.body.content
        },{returnDocument: 'after'}, (err, foundArticle) => {
            err ? res.send("Error !") : foundArticle ? res.send(foundArticle) : res.send("NO articles found to update!")
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), `findOneAndUpdate()`:

> [...] finds the first document that matches a given
> filter, applies an update, and returns the document. By default, findOneAndUpdate() **returns the document as it was before
> update was applied.**

To actually return the updated document, the documentation suggests to do the following:

> You should set the new option to true to return the document after
> update was applied.

The third argument to the method is an optional `options` object where a `new` parameter can be set to `true` in order to actually return the updated document.

To actually access the updated document after the method call, there are multiple ways of doing so.

**Example 1: Using async/await syntax**

```js
const doc = await Article.findOneAndUpdate(
    { title: req.params.articleTitle },
    {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    },
    { new: true }
)

doc.title // equals value of req.body.title
```

**Example 2: Using `.then()` syntax**

```js
Article.findOneAndUpdate(
    { title: req.params.articleTitle },
    {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    },
    { new: true }
).then((err, doc) => {
    console.log(doc.title) // equals value of req.body.title
})
```

**Example 3: Using the callback syntax**

```js
Article.findOneAndUpdate(
    { title: req.params.articleTitle },
    {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    },
    { new: true },
    (err, doc) => {
        console.log(doc.title) // equals value of req.body.title
    })
```